# Approximating a probability from independent trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I am running simulations for a particular problem, which is not relevant to my question. Every simulation takes non-trivial amount of time and its result is binary - either 0 or 1, with probabilities $1-p$ and $p$ respectively. If I run $N$ simulations and get $x$ $1$'s, then $\frac{x}{N}$ is my approximation of $p$. My question is - which theorem/inequality is most commonly used to decide how big $N$ should be to be quite certain my error isn't too big? Does the answer change if I add additional information about $p$ (for example $p > 0.01$ and $p < 0.99$)? Obviously I would like $N$ not to be too big, to minimise running time of my simulations while still being quite certain that my approximation is accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard deviation after $N$ trials is$\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{N}}$.  Since you have only an estimate for $p$, use $N-1$ rather than $N$ for estimating standard deviation.  You need to decide how small the standard deviation has to be to satisfy your requirement.

The formula is from Bernoulli trials.

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful. How can I intuitively understand the fact that the standard deviation is the highest at $p = \frac{1}{2}$ and gets smaller and smaller with p?

Comment: @user132290 Maximize $f(p)=p(1-p)$ and evaluate if $f^{''}(p^*)<0$,  where $f^{'}(p^*)=0$.

Comment: I am not asking how to show it, that is trivial. I am asking about how to think about it in intuitive terms.

Comment: @user132290 $f(p)=p(1-p)$ is a parabola. Since $a=-1$ is negative the parabola opens downward. Therefore there exists exatly one maximum and no minimum. The value of $p^*$ is in the middle of $p=0$ and $p=1$ (roots). Better now?

Comment: When p is near 0 or near 1 the distribution tends to have a narrow width.  In the extreme case, p=0 or p=1, there is no width at all.